# White Space around JPanel in Boxlayout?

Tags: java, swing

I'm building a GUI with several JPanels and with a BoxLayout with Y-axis. I also use borders with titles around the JPanels. I wonder if it's possible to control the space between the border of the JPanel and the window frame? I'm also wondering if it's possible to justify the content inside the JPanels to the left or right? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an `EmptyBorder` using `CompoundBorder` to wrap both, the current border and the emtpy one. The empty border would not be rendered but allow you to define the margin to the frame using insets.

The justification of the panel's content would depend on the layout manager used there. Do you have a `BoxLayout` inside the panel as well?

*Edit*:

A really good and easy to use layout manager is [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). It allows defining custom insets, alignment etc. inline and using just a single layoutmanager.

Comment: Hi! No I just add the components to the JPanel and therefore get a centered position. It would look better if it's to left?

Comment: I'm not using NetBeans! I do it by hand....or trying to learn doing it by hand, but comparing how easy it is to webdesign it's frustrating!

Comment: @3D-kreativ sometimes it's even easier than web design, provided you have the right layout manager. I'm using MigLayout and it's really easy and straight forward. I'll add the link in my answer so that others can find it.